# Why does a class inherit from a struct

Tags: ruby

Is

```
class A < Struct.new(:att)
end
```

the same as

```
class A
  attr_accessor :att
end
```

in Ruby?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. It is equal to

```
B = Struct.new(:att)
class A < B; end
```

which is pretty much equivalent, but not equal to

```
class B
  attr_accesor :att
  def initialize(att)
    @att = att
  end
end

class A < B
end
```

Not equal because the value is not actually stored in `@att`:

```
B = Struct.new(:att)

class B
  def real_att
    @att
  end
end
b = B.new(32)
b.att
# => 32
b.real_att
# => nil
```

Personally, I don't see why one wouldn't just do `A = Struct.new(:att)`, without the inheritance business.

**EDIT**: As Jordan notes in comments, there is an even nicer way to add methods to a struct: the `Struct` conStructor (teehee) takes a block, which executes in the context of the newly created class: whatever you define there, will be defined on the new struct.

```
B = Struct.new(:att) do
  def process
    #...
  end
end
```

Comment: Normally you'd inherit from `Struct.new(:att)` if you needed a named class that was sort of like a Hash with accessors and an extra method or two. A common example would be `class SomeDelayedJob < Struct.new(...); def perform ...`.

Comment: @muistooshort: Yeah, that's one line shorter than defining the constant directly then reopening the class; but also gives you an extra inheritance layer. I suppose that's a matter of style.

Comment: Thanks.  I saw it there https://github.com/zinenko/vk-ruby/blob/master/lib/vk-ruby/auth_params.rb#L3

Comment: Yup, as @muistooshort says, make a `Struct` and add some methods. One line shorter and one inheritance longer (but I might be wrong about this part) than what my `real_att` example shows; otherwise equivalent.

Comment: If you want to define methods on your Struct you should pass a block to `Struct.new`, e.g. `B = Struct.new(:att) do; def foo; ... end end`. `class B < Struct.new(:att)` is an antipattern.

Comment: @Jordan: TIL `Struct.new` can take a block. Thanks, that's neat.

Comment: Here's some reasons you may or may not want to inherit from `Struct`: https://thepugautomatic.com/2013/08/struct-inheritance-is-overused/

Answer (score 0):

> Why does a class inherit from a struct

<s>It doesn't.  Classes inherit from other classes.</s>  In ruby, to create an inheritance hierarchy you can write:

```
class A
  def bark
    puts "woof"
  end
end

class B < A
end

B.new.bark

--output:--
woof
```

But, you can also do this:

```
class A
  def bark
    puts "woof"
  end
end

def do_stuff
  return A
end

class B < do_stuff
end

B.new.bark

--output:--
woof
```

Is that a class that inherits from a method?  No!  Ruby lets you use an arbitrary expression for the parent class--as long as it returns a class.  The code:

```
Struct.new(:att)
```

is an arbitrary expression which returns a class:

```
x = Struct.new(:att)
p x

--output:--
#<Class:0x007f8c3126c568>
```

Comment: Technically, *technically*, OP is correct: the class does inherit from a Struct: `Struct.new(:att) < Struct` is true :P